# Was I right or wrong to value the following as an opening hand?

Tags: bridge, bidding

At matchpoints, not vulnerable vs. vulnerable, I opened one heart with the following (all X's are 7 or lower).

```
♠ J9x
♡ A9xxxx
♢ J9
♣ AT
```

Normally, I need 11, not 10, high card points to open even with a good six card suit. Here I "stretched" with 10 because of the two doubletons and good intermediates (three 9s and a T).

Partner raised to game with 12 points (opening hand), we went down one, losing one trick in each suit, and got a bottom on the board.

Was this an unlucky result? Or did I overbid?

Comment: Which seat were you in?

Comment: @ruds: Mine was first seat. Are you saying that the opening would have been more appropriate for third or fourth seat?

Comment: Jx is worth maybe at most 0.5 a high card point, though aces are worth more than 4.  I wouldn't open this in 1st or 2nd seat even in my light opening Precision partnership!  I think this is a fine weak 2 though.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: If I had it to do over again, I would open this a "weak two" in first or second seat, and 1H only in third or fourth seat.

Comment: @TomAu: I'm a firm believer that your weak 2 range in 3rd seat should be about 0-14 hcp.  As long as game isn't a possibility, partner doesn't need to know how strong you are; any strength limitations only provides information to your LHO.  (Partner does need to know about your length to make Law of Total Tricks decisions.)  In 4th seat, most people play weak 2s show about 10-12 hcp and a 6 card suit (you just pass with weaker hands, which aren't really possible), though some play that 'weak' 2s show 13-15 and a 6 card suit in 4th seat.  So I would open this hand 2H in all seats.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: You'd go as high as 14 for a "weak two" bid? My club considers "10" the max (except for my one, conservative partner, who liked my call with 12 points.) https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49481/did-i-really-have-too-many-points-for-the-following-bid. And "Forget" had strong words about my "underbidding."

Comment: I think every partner I have had recently and I have made the standing agreement that 'preemptive' bids (including preemptive overcalls) *opposite a passed hand* can be made with any strength as long as there is no possibility of game.  Officially according to ACBL rules this does not require an alert but we do alert it for less experienced opponents who might not expect it.  It's a common treatment that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @TomAu: The linked hand had enough distribution that game was a possibility opposite the right passed hand.  You don't just count points; you also have to imagine partner's possible hands.

Comment: What is a 14 point hand with six of a suit that has no possibility of game opposite a passed hand. I would pass with 10 points or a bad 11, and 14+10=24, which often makes one a candidate for game (if a slight underdog).

Comment: @TomAu: Yes it would have to be a terrible 14 - something like AJxxxx QJx QJ QJ (that's 8 losers!)

Answer (score 4):

Opening that hand would be very aggressive, and not something I'd support.

- You have *maybe* ten points.  J9 of diamonds is pretty much zero, that neither is likely to take a trick nor is likely to help anything partner has take a trick unless partner is long in diamonds (in which case you'd just ruff the long ones anyway).
- You don't have a good heart suit.  You could easily lose three heart tricks with that suit.
- Your spade jack is also pretty mediocre.

Don't count length AND shortness - count one or the other, if you're counting points.  This is the *worst* distribution with a six card suit, remember, from a distribution-point perspective - you *have* to have two doubletons (or shorter) with a six card suit.

I'd be pretty upset if you opened this 1h opposite me.  I also don't love 2h here (with only Ah and an outside ace, this isn't screaming "interfere") but certainly some would, especially in higher level competition.

Your partner needs to be able to trust that you're in a particular range when you open.  Your bidding with this hand either means your partnership ends up in slams/games that you shouldn't be... or it means your partner adds a point to ranges, but then ends up not bidding games/slams you *should* be in.  Both are not good.

Comment: If I had it to do again, I would open a "weak two" rather than at the "one" level. I consider A, KQ, or QJT equivalent "headers" for my six card suit, and I like the side ace in a short suit, as well as the top of the 5-10 range.

Comment: You're certainly welcome to, and I think some would value it that way.  I generally wouldn't, as I like my weak 2s to be a little more predictable.

Comment: Re "predictable," I believe my "weak twos" are pretty well defined. Six card suit. One sure "top" trick (A, KQ, or QJT) to go with three "long" tricks, and no more than one defensive trick outside. Point range is less important to me than "functionality."